# Numlock default off on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.10, numlock

Every boot, my NUM-lock is off. Few weeks back always on. I don't have this function in BIOS.
So I think, this issue came with some an update.
Any advice? I don't like to try numlockx . Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use numlockx? It's pretty straightforward and easy to use.

Comment: I tried and not works. Nothing happen after numlockx on command.

Comment: That's because the command is just `/usr/bin/numlockx` in your autostart section.

Comment: So how to fix ? Thank you.

Comment: First install it with `sudo apt install numlockx`. Then click the 9 dot menu in the lower left, type 'startup' and click on startup applications, click on add, name it something that means something to you, put `/usr/bin/numlockx` in the command section, and save it. Reboot and numlock should be on.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have dual boot. It's off on login screen.

Comment: Dual boot wouldn't impact it. It works here without a hitch. I tested it on 20.10 before giving you the answer to ensure it was correct. Perhaps you missed a step.

Comment: Numlock is on after login. However not at login screen.

Comment: Something has to have been changed on your system. I'll have some free time this evening. I'll see if I can recreate what's going on with your system. (It works here.) Are you using Wayland?

Comment: I am using default settings on login. However I notice some changes after updates. I can even open text files. It shows weird symbols. It was just today update, something like openSSH. Maybe it will works after this repair.

Comment: @Emvo Confirmed **not working** on `Ubuntu Studio 20.10`